# Is there faster way to find placeholder template in string

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, replace

I have string like this:

```
This is item: {item.ITEMNAME} and it's width is: {item.ITEMWIDTH}...
```

I need to get all this placeholders but now I am doing it manually like:

```
if (indexOf('{item.') > 0) {
  // get a list of all placeholders
  // Loop through all and try to replace
}
```

This is probably slow is there a way to make this more generic and extract all like:

```
let array = string.find('{item.???}');
```

Comment: Regex is your friend. `str.replace(/\{([^\}]+)\}/g, (_, p) => console.log(p));`

Comment: I don't know how to construct regex like this

Comment: Time to learn then: http://regular-expressions.info.

Comment: Use template literals

Comment: Template literals would indeed be preferrable, if the string doesn't come from an outside, untouchable source.

Comment: @ASDFGerte it is comning from server you can add answervwith regex if tou like that solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Could you append a dollar sign before each opening curly brace?

Then you could use an ES6 [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
let item = {
  ITEMNAME : 'Foo',
  ITEMWIDTH : '100%'
}

let str = `This is item: ${item.ITEMNAME} and its width is: ${item.ITEMWIDTH}...`

console.log(str)
```

Comment: I can't add $ but `str.replace(/\{([^\}]+)\}/g` seems to work. But thanks I will keep this in mind for future.